# rails g install doesnt work, just returns usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm trying to install [blazer](https://github.com/ankane/blazer#installation) and using rails, it seems that my generate command is missing... I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to RoR and Ruby in general. This is my output.

```
root@456a4f4bd0b1:/blazer-app# bundle exec rails g blazer:install
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                      # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
```

I'm running the following:

```
root@456a4f4bd0b1:/blazer-app# gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actioncable (5.1.2, 5.0.2)
actionmailer (5.1.2, 5.0.2)
actionpack (5.1.2, 5.0.2)
actionview (5.1.2, 5.0.2)
activejob (5.1.2, 5.0.2)
activemodel (5.1.2, 5.0.2)
activerecord (5.1.2, 5.0.2)
activesupport (5.1.2, 5.0.2)
arel (8.0.0, 7.1.4)
bigdecimal (default: 1.2.8)
blazer (1.8.0)
builder (3.2.3)
bundler (1.13.6)
chartkick (2.2.4)
concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
did_you_mean (1.0.0)
errbase (0.0.3)
erubi (1.6.1)
erubis (2.7.0)
factory_girl (4.8.0)
factory_girl_rails (4.8.0)
globalid (0.4.0)
i18n (0.8.6)
io-console (default: 0.4.5)
json (default: 1.8.3)
loofah (2.0.3)
mail (2.6.6)
method_source (0.8.2)
mime-types (3.1)
mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
mini_portile2 (2.2.0)
minitest (5.10.2, 5.8.3)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
nio4r (2.1.0)
nokogiri (1.8.0)
power_assert (0.2.6)
psych (default: 2.0.17)
rack (2.0.3)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails (5.1.2, 5.0.2)
rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
railties (5.1.2, 5.0.2)
rake (10.5.0, 10.4.2)
rdoc (default: 4.2.1)
rubygems-update (2.6.8)
safely_block (0.2.0)
sprockets (3.7.1)
sprockets-rails (3.2.0)
test-unit (3.1.5)
thor (0.19.4)
thread_safe (0.3.6)
tzinfo (1.2.3)
websocket-driver (0.6.5)
websocket-extensions (0.1.2)

root@456a4f4bd0b1:/blazer-app# rails -v
Rails 5.1.2

root@456a4f4bd0b1:/blazer-app# ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]
```

Current tree structure and present working directory

```
root@456a4f4bd0b1:# tree -L 2
.
|-- CHANGELOG.md
|-- Gemfile
|-- Gemfile.lock
|-- LICENSE.txt
|-- README.md
|-- Rakefile
|-- app
|   |-- assets
|   |-- controllers
|   |-- helpers
|   |-- mailers
|   |-- models
|   `-- views
|-- blazer.gemspec
|-- config
|   `-- routes.rb
|-- false
|-- lib
|   |-- blazer
|   |-- blazer.rb
|   |-- generators
|   `-- tasks
`-- pkg
    `-- blazer-1.8.0.gem
```

I've tried removing my `Gemfile.lock` running `bundle install` and `bundle update` with the same output for rails.

What's weird is that I also tried running the `rails db:migrate` command, and `rails` isn't aware of the task!

Answer (score 0):

are you in the rails app?
aka not the directory you made it, but you cd into the file after

```
rails new Appname
```

i think your in the directory and not the actual rails file

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My present working directory is `/blazer-app` and I have the `Rakefile` in that directory. I added a `tree` output to my question. I'm sure it's something foolish I'm doing though.

Comment: i only said that cause of the error message, its also seen when no rails file present